# Products do not appear on list page in magento 2?

Tags: product-collection, magento2.3, cataloginventory

I am working on a project where I need to display the list products on list page. I have added the products on local server where I am getting them on front-end. But when I create products on live site. I am getting

> "Available Stock:0"

in **Magento 2.3**.

When I went to check the n.o of products in list.phtml using **count()** function it **return 0**. But on local it return right value and display the products as well.

I have tried **Reindexing** as well but got no luck. Kindly help me out!!!
If you need further clarification please let me know.

Comment: There must be indexing issue, please run re-index and try it again

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, I have tried that multiple time. But no luck

Comment: please check your log files, check if any error over there

Comment: Possibly, what could be the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No I have no idea but you can get errors when you load category page if any

Comment: @ShahzadAhmed please check this, it may help you https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Products-not-showing-on-front-end/td-p/102534

Comment: Hi @GPrathap. One thing I forgot to mention is that. When I revert my theme to luma. Still I don't get the products. What do you suggest to cater this?

Comment: @ShahzadAhmed Do you have any custom modules? if so just try disable all those and try again with luma theme. It may work.

Comment: yes I have one custom module in my theme. But, it works absolutely fine on my local website.

Comment: I got ride of this error finally after a new Magento installation. It was not installed properly.